# How to hide m3u8 url

Tags: javascript, node.js, m3u8

I am broadcasting live tv with m3u8 on my site. But when I monitor the network traffic of my site, I cannot hide the m3u8 link and the .ts links in it are visible. How can I hide these .ts links on nodejs?

Example m3u8 file: https://sosyoapp-live.cdnnew.com/sosyo/buraya-bir-isim-verin.m3u8

I converted ts links to mp4 and ran them on my server, but I could not get full efficiency.

Comment: How is the client supposed to locate the resource if you hide the Uniform Resource Locator?

Comment: @Quentin How can I make it work if I hide the link structure and only have the referrer url?

Comment: @Quentin or how can I make it look like it's broadcasting from my own site and not from a remote server?

Comment: One solution to hide the m3u8 URL is to use a reverse proxy. With a reverse proxy, you can route the traffic to your m3u8 file through a different URL that is under your control. The reverse proxy can then fetch the m3u8 file and any associated .ts files on your behalf and return the content to the client. This way, the client will only see the reverse proxy URL and not the original m3u8 URL.

Comment: Another option is to use a server-side script to dynamically generate the m3u8 file based on the user's request. In this case, you can use the script to fetch the necessary .ts files and return the content to the client. The m3u8 URL would not be accessible directly, and the .ts URLs would be hidden from the client.

Comment: If you're using Node.js, you can use a library like Express or Hapi to implement the reverse proxy or the server-side script.

Comment: Interesting that you're sharing the URL you're trying to hide.

Comment: It's also worth noting that hiding the m3u8 URL will not necessarily improve the efficiency of your streaming setup. The efficiency of the streaming process will depend on some factors, such as the network conditions, the encoding settings, and the hardware and software that you're using.

Comment: @HafizurRahman Thank you for your answer, can you give some more information on how exactly I can do this? Can you help me write a code block?

Comment: @leshcode I added it as an answer.

Comment: When I enter localhost:3000/proxy, my m3u8 file is automatically live without any problems. When I add video tags on the Safari side, I can watch it without any problems, but I cannot open it in chrome and other browsers. I used "application/x-mpegURL" and "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" as Mime Type. I can't get results from any browser other than safari :( @HafizurRahman